# AppleScript: start/stop QuickTime Player screen recording on timer

Tags: applescript, screen-capture, quicktime

I would like to use an AppleScript which will tell QuickTime Player to start screen recording immediately and stop screen recording after a specified length of time (e.g. 60 mins).

In my search so far, I have come across this AppleScript:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set newScreenRecording to new screen recording
    tell newScreenRecording
        start
        delay 3
        stop
    end tell
    tell last item of documents
        close
    end tell
end tell
```

but I get an error message saying "the variable new screen recording is not defined". I don't know anything about programming as you can probably tell so I'd really appreciate any help you can offer with this.

Comment: h_value__lux, Welcome to Ask Different! I have tested the _code_ shown in your question and it worked without issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I wonder what I am doing wrong. I copied and pasted it into Applescript and I still get the error message.

Comment: If you are using Catalina, then there is a different way of doing it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374076/how-to-screen-record-using-applescript-on-catalina

Comment: h_value__lux, Sorry, I tested your _code_ under **macOS High Sierra** and testing now under **macOS Catalina** it does fail with the error message your stated. See my answer: [A: How to screen record using AppleScript on Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374076/how-to-screen-record-using-applescript-on-catalina/374114?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#374114)

Answer (score 1):

To stop the recording I did this and it worked fine, just change the delay seconds to 3600 (60 minutes), this will press control + cmd + esc to stop the screen recording after 5000 seconds

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 5000
    key code 53 using {control down, command down} -- shift-command-left
end tell
```

I haven't researched how to start it, I started it manually

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's not pretty, but if you click to start the video this will stop it.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    new screen recording
end tell

--Pause for 10 seconds
delay 10

--Click the stop recording button in the top menu bar.
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of application process "screencaptureui"
end tell
```

Pro tip: Record yourself doing the action you want to automate in automator, drag and drop that operation into a new window and copy the line where it says `click menu...` (Remove the "\" escape characters) into a simple `tell application "System Events"` command. But unfortunately it doesn't work for everything.

Comment: The result of running your _code_ in **macOS Catalina** is: '**error** "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu bar 1 of application process \"screencaptureui\". Invalid index." number -1719 from menu bar 1 of application process "screencaptureui"'